# Sonarqube with maven - Cannot register highlighting rule for characters

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I'm trying to execute `mvn sonar:sonar`, but I'm getting the **error below**:

```
[INFO] [18:56:51.281] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: pt_BR
[INFO] [18:56:52.136] Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[INFO] [18:56:54.000] Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 1864 ms
[INFO] [18:56:54.000] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [18:56:54.296] Java AST scan...
[ERROR] [18:56:54.629] Cannot register highlighting rule for characters from 879
9 to 8809 as it overlaps at least one existing rule
[ERROR] Sonar is unable to analyze file : 'D:\..\..\..\HelperForEntitiesBusiness.java'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar
```

Have you ever seen the error **Cannot register highlighting rule for characters from 879
    9 to 8809 as it overlaps at least one existing rule** ?

Comment: Could you please provide the versions of SonarQube and the Java plugin? Could you also provide the error stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it really was the problem, but I added the following into my pom.xml and now everything is working fine.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>windows-1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same error but it was caused by the sonar CSS plugin. Did you see anything related to css above the errors you posted? By setting the language to java you essentially disable multi-language analysis which then disables analysing of CSS completely.

If you saw the css errors you can also prevent this from happening if you uninstall the CSS plugin in sonar, then you do not have to change the build xml's for each project.

More info from sonar mailing list: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.sonar.general/38055

Comment: Funny how there were 3 negative comments within minutes when I forgot to include the proper info, but once it's there, nobody blinks an eye :)